# Talking,Pulling from a database SQL lastest five image thumbs and link to them

Tags: html, sql, database

I am trying to pull the latest five image thumbs from my booru datebase (I've been told this is the best way) yet I have no idea how to do this.

I will get all the info you might need as I might miss some.

Here is the image datebase layout:

[image]

And this is the site
http://animelon.com/booru/

An example of what am trying to do is pull 5 thumbs just like you see on that URL above on to a custom html page, When the thumb/s are clicked it will take you to the main image page 
Example http://animelon.com/booru/post/view/211337

If you need anymore info please ask.

Comment: In the future you should post the schema as text, the image is very annoying.

Comment: How can I do that? I did google sql layout help but didn't find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the SQL you need.  You will need to use PHP or a similar language to connect to the DB and return the results to your application.

```
SELECT id, filename, width, height, ext, posted
FROM images
ORDER BY posted DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

Create links based on the data from the rows:

```
for loop...
$row = odbc_fetch_array($result);
$output .= "<img src=\"".$row['filename'].$row['ext']."\" width=\"".$row['width']."\" height=\"".$row['height']."\"/>;
```

I left a lot of code out of the PHP, its just so you can get an idea.

Comment: Thanks man my php is not great(pretty crap lol) but I will have a play that's for sure! thanks again

Comment: The good thing is that there are a ton of resources out there, its pretty easy once you get the hang of it.